# ¿Como puedo hacer una suma en bucle)

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy intentado crear un comando que cuando lo ejecute empiece con el valor 1, y cada 3 segundos el valor se sume un 0.2 resultando un 1.2, y después de otros 3 segundos el resultado será 1.4 y así sucesivamente.

Utilicé un Interval de esta manera

```
const msge = await message.channel.send(1)
setInterval(() => {
    msge.edit(+0.2)
}, 3*1000 /* cada 3s */)
```

Pero lo que sucede es que el mensaje se cambia por 0.2 y no lo suma, no encuentro ninguna manera de hacer esto y necesito ayuda, si sabéis como hacerlo agradecería una mano.

Comment: Deberías tener una variable donde se haga la operación, porque supongo que el método `.send()` solo envía lo que recibe por parámetro.

Comment: creo que deberás declara una variable afuera e ir sumando a esa variable, `.edit()` recibe como parámetro la nueva edición del mensaje y tu le pasas el valor de `0.2`

Comment: Si te permite operar tal vez funcione con un +=0.2, sino algo como un this+=0.2, sino con una variable como te sugieren.

Comment: @Emeeus eso es parte de discordjs, lo malo es que no existe tal etiqueta

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres ir sumando el valor, utiliza una variable adicional para mantener el último valor enviado. En cada ejecución del intervalo, vas aumentando el valor de dicha variable, por ejemplo:

```
let valor = 1;
const msge = await message.channel.send(valor)

setInterval(() => {
    valor += 0.2;
    msge.edit(valor);
}, 3*1000 /* cada 3s */)
```